# Angular 8 loads javascript from wrong path after reload on lazy loaded module

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular8

when I reload the page when I'm on lazy loaded module the app breaks as it tries to import js files from the wrong path. you can see my routing configuration:
app routing module:

```
{
  path: 'accommodations',
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  loadChildren: () => import('./accommodation/accommodation.module').then(m => m.AccommodationModule)
}
```

accommodation routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: AccommodationDetailsComponent
  }
];
```

when I'm on route http://localhost:4200/accommodations/1 for example and I reload the page, browser tries to import js files from http://localhost:4200/accommodations and shows 404 error.
for example, it tries to import runtime js from http://localhost:4200/accommodations/runtime.js

Comment: Welcome to SO, please try to put some more effort into your question if you expect good answers. Post your relevant code and full error messages and stack trace don't just link images.

Comment: Seems like you are not using the Angular CLI, am I right?

Comment: @PierreDuc I do use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt' find the problem itself, but i found that if I use `useHash:true` the error goes away